# using scale.category10() and scale.sqrt with domain ? clamp ? range?

Tags: d3.js

Who is able to explain me this code:

```
var hue = d3.scale.category10();
var luminance = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .domain([0, 1e6])
    .clamp(true)
    .range([90, 20]);
```

It's for L*a*b notation color

Can someone explain me step by step with example please this part of code? Because I have percent value and I'm thinking the domain or range are not for percent value in luminance function for this `luminance(d.sum);` I have always this value for luminance: `89.9999951176645`

Is that the problem because my `d.sum` are around `0.9` and `0.9`

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation? Everything is explained quite nicely there. The `.domain()` specifies the range of input values, so you would need to set that according to what you want to pass in.

Comment: The `luminance` scale in your example is set up to take values between 0 and a million and spit out values between 90 and 20. You pass it 0.9. Well, that's almost 0 (compared to a million), which is why you get back a value that's very close to 90.

Comment: oh thank you ... I just set from 1 to 100 in domain and when I use luminance function I multiplicate my d.sum by 100 like that: luminance(d.sum+100) because my d.sum are 0.8465 or 0.06534 or 0.0034 ... ans so on :)  and now I have nice gradient ^^ THank you very much my friend :)